# IOS setting the Storyboard built layout as rtl

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, uistoryboard

I have built a storyboard as a RTL layout in consideration for use in a single language(hebrew),

Now i need to add an english option but the autolayout is mirroring in opposite as natively the storyboard is LTR,

In sum, i have an RTL on a LTR storyboard and i can't find a way to change the storyboard setting from the default LTR to RTL so that the auto mirroring will match the languages,

The language in my info.plist is set to "he",
I have edited the project files so the development language is hebrew,

Is there any way to fix the situation without re-building all the story board?

Thanks,